# How to Download and Convert You tube Videos With Video Download Studio?

Tags: video, download, youtube

I have video download studio and I want to download some videos from you tube but there appears to be some problem when I I do it. How should I do it properly?

Comment: _"...but there appears to be some problem when I I do it."_ Telling us what's exactly happening would greatly improve the possibility that you receive an answer.

Comment: You need to precise your question with more details about your problem. You say there is "some problem", what is it? If you have an error message, tell us what it is. If you want quality help, you need to provide more details. "Help us help you", in short.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do streaming videos download works?](https://superuser.com/questions/320325/how-do-streaming-videos-download-works)

Answer (score 2):

You can't "properly" download videos from YouTube, you have to agree not to in order to use YouTube:

> you agree not to access User Videos (as defined below) for any reason other than your personal, non-commercial use solely as intended through and permitted by the normal functionality of the Services, and solely for Streaming. "Streaming" means a contemporaneous digital transmission of the material by YouTube via the Internet to a user operated Internet enabled device in such a manner that the data is intended for real-time viewing and not intended to be downloaded (either permanently or temporarily), copied, stored, or redistributed by the user.

— http://www.youtube.com/t/terms